# How to handle Google Maps API V3 event in multiple promise chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, promise, deferred

I have a setup where on page load, if there is a query value in the URL (?st=CA&s=park..." etc) the javascript uses fetch to grab a JSON file with some data in it.

On the return promise of the fetch, the JSON data is then passed to 3 other promises, one of create some html, one to create some select field values, and finally, one creates a Google Map.  After all this, there is a full screen overlay that fades out and the different elements (gmaps, selects, html) of the page animate in using Motion UI series animations.

The issue I'm having is how to let the Promise.all([]).then() know that the google "tilesloaded" event has fired.  The reason is that if the map is still rendering while the animations take place, there is a fair amount of jank, the animations are not that smooth.

The basic code/logic looks like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var query = bsky_GetQueryFromURL(); // gets ?cat=23,43&state=CA
    var data_P = bsky_GetCampaignProjects(); // gets JSON file with fetch

    if (! $.isEmptyObject(query)) {

        data_P
            .then(data => bsky_FilterData(data, query)) // filters data by query
            .then(data => bsky_MakeQueryView(data))
            .then(values => {
                bksy_Animation_QueryView_IN();
            });

    } else {

        bsky_MakeNoQueryView();

    }
});

function bsky_MakeQueryView(data) {
    var gMap_P = bsky_setupGoogleMap(data);
    var pHTML_P = bsky_setupProjectsList(data);
    var selects_P = bsky_setupRefineBySelects(data)

    return Promise.all([gMap_P, pHTML_P, selects_P]);
}
```

The Google Maps event I want to be able to know if is complete before I run the animate in function is,

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "tilesloaded", function() { });
```

Is there a way to do this via deferred or promise?

```
function bsky_setupGoogleMap(subset) {
    var options = {
        scrollwheel: false,
        //navigationControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        //scaleControl: false,
        //draggable: false,
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.8333333,-98.585522),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var markerImage = '';

    $(subset).each(function(k,v) {

        if (v.geo.national == 0) {
            var geo = v.geo.gmap;

            if (geo.hasOwnProperty('lat') && geo.hasOwnProperty('lng')) {
                var lat = parseInt(geo.lat);
                var lng = parseInt(geo.lng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
                    map: map,
                    title:v.project.title,
                    //icon: markerImage
                });
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: bsky_Template_GMapInfoWindow(v),
                    maxWidth: 260
                });

                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    var iw_container = $(".gm-style-iw").parent();
                    iw_container.stop().hide();
                    iw_container.fadeIn(1000);
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.close();
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {

                    var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');
                    var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

                    iwOuter.parent().parent().css({left: '135px'});
                    iwBackground.children(':nth-child(1)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 10px !important;'});
                    iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 10px !important;'});

                });

                bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
            }
        }
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() { 
        if (map.getZoom() > 9) map.setZoom(11); 
            google.maps.event.removeListener(listener); 
    });

    return;
}
```

It maybe I have an answer - easier than I was thinking?

```
    function bsky_setupGoogleMaps(data) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     // ... all the google map code from above
     // then add this and resolve
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "tilesloaded", function() { 
            resolve('tilesloaded');
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: It seems the promise returned by `bsky_setupGoogleMaps()` should resolve in response to the "tilesloaded" event. It's hard to advise further without seeing `bsky_setupGoogleMaps()`.

Comment: Hi Roamer - that sounds about right to me, but how to resolve a promise from an event hook?  I added the bsky_setupGoogleMap() function.

Comment: Looks good now, though you might like to consider (a) doing "all the google map code from above" outside the Promise constructor, otherwise (in the absence of a catch()) errors will be swallowed. (b) simplifying the addListerner statement to `google.maps.event.addListener(map, "tilesloaded", resolve)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function bsky_setupGoogleMaps(data) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // ... all the google map code from above
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "tilesloaded", resolve);
    });
}
```